# "warning: section "__const_coal" is deprecated" error after updating Xcode to latest version on Mac OS

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, compiler-errors, g++

My g++ compiler for C++ program was working fine until I updated my Xcode to the latest version and accepted the license agreement. I also tried compiling with clang instead of g++ but got errors. Now I get a long stream of errors. Anyone has an idea what is wrong?

```
Ivans-MacBook-Pro:CS6771A3-GenericDirectedWeightedGraph ivanteong$ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Werror -O2 -o test6 tests/test6.cpp
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccZfBPvE.s:1:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccZfBPvE.s:1:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccZfBPvE.s:211:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccZfBPvE.s:211:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccZfBPvE.s:604:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccZfBPvE.s:604:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Try omitting the flag `-O2` in your compile command.

Comment: Still problematic. I also omitted -0 and still same problem.

Comment: I just realised that after I uninstalled Xcode, when I do "xcode-select -p", it does not point at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" (which is when Xcode is installed) but points at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools" instead. When it is pointing to the latter, I have no problems compiling with gcc again.

This means that the command line tool that was pointed to when Xcode 8 is installed is the non-working one, right?

Coz now with Xcode uninstalled, it seems the command line tools are pointed at a different folder by default, and that one doesn't crash the gcc compiler.

Comment: Yeah I'd say good observation on that — so maybe it's some type of linker issue perhaps?

Comment: Maybe but I can't be 100% sure. I haven't taken a course on compilers to fully understand it lol.

Comment: If you have a small example of the code it might help to see if the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Which code? Whatever error I got is not coz of the program I was trying to compile, it's due to the compiler itself relying on the command line tools. I already posted whatever compiler error I got above.

Comment: The code you are compiling doesn't contain `__textcoal_nt`?

Comment: Nope it doesn't contain that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was getting the exact same warnings on updating to Xcode v8.0. However, you do not need to uninstall Xcode. Rather, you need to set the path of the active developer directory:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: Yep this is the solution. I got Xcode 8 with gcc working now. Cheers!

Comment: @Kingiol You can install the command line tools with:
`xcode-select --install`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, anyone else know another fix for the problem