# warning section "_textcoal_nt is deprecated

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I have recently updated my xcode to version 8 and now there is an error when I archive my app. This is the error:

```
section "_textcoal_nt" is deprecated
```

and

```
section "_consta_coal" is deprecated
```

see screenshot:

[image: deprecation messages]

this is inside the output box

```
2016-09-18 22:29:58.170742 Hindi Love Stories[2267:613868] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2016-09-18 22:29:59.803390 Hindi Love Stories[2267:613868] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2016-09-18 22:29:59.803920 Hindi Love Stories[2267:613868] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

could not find solution for this, please guy help me out how to fix this issue.

I dont know much about xcode so may be this is not easy for me

I have searched all around and I am very new to apple developing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502921/warning-section-const-coal-is-deprecated-error-after-updating-xcode-to-la

Comment: have you solved this? And are you using the Google Mobile Ads sdk?

Comment: not yet, yes i am using Google Mobile Ads