# Xcode 8 warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I recently updated to Xcode 8 on el-cap.

I did an "xcode-select --install" earlier today, and also ran brew to get a couple of commands installed.  I also updated a Podfile and then cranked up Xcode 8, which I haven't done for the particular project I'm working on until now.

When I compile for the simulator, I get no warnings.  When I Archive (to get ready to upload to the App Store), I get several of the following:

```
warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT, __textcoal_nt, coalesced, pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT, __textcoal_nt, coalesced, pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: section "__const_coal" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT, __const_coal, coalesced
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: change section name to "__const"
        .section __TEXT, __const_coal, coalesced
```

Now, this only happens when i archive with an iOS project.  I don't see this for a tvOS project.

Any idea what's going on here?   I've seen other questions that point at this error (see:  ["warning: section "__const_coal" is deprecated" error after updating Xcode to latest version on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502921/warning-section-const-coal-is-deprecated-error-after-updating-xcode-to-la) ), but they all appear to want to work exclusively on the command line.  I want this to work through Xcode.   I reset everything, reinstalled Xcode 8, and still have this issue.  Here's where my command lines are currently pointing:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Any ideas?

PS (I did try pointing at the CommandTools directory listed in the answer in the URL above, but this didn't help).

EDIT:

Those that suggested I do the command line tool install and -s to those utilities, I had already tried that (see original post).  I did it again just to be sure and it did not work.

The install said the files already existed, the switch to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools, reboot, and starting Xcode has the same results.  The command line path in Xcode still shows it as
     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Preferences in Xcode under "Locations" shows "Command Line Tools" blank when I switched to "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools" on the command line, but still showed the PATH above when I tried to relink.   It appears Xcode 8 just ignores it.

Comment: Run these on terminal "xcode-select --install" and then "sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools"

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["warning: section "\_\_const\_coal" is deprecated" error after updating Xcode to latest version on Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502921/warning-section-const-coal-is-deprecated-error-after-updating-xcode-to-la)