# Unnecessary assembly code output from compiling C++ after upgrading to macOS Sierra (.section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I upgraded my Mac OS to the latest public release of macOS Sierra, and every time I compile a C++ program, I will get a bunch of assembly code output.

I've read on other sites that the assembly code output does not mean that my program had any problems compiling, but that Command Line Tools have some changes due to the underlying system changes for the compiler, which is why the assembly code is being regurgitated. However, I want to rid the unnecessary assembly code output.

I've tried changing the path of the Command Line Tools with

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTool
```

and

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

(which is where Xcode is installed) and checking with

```
xcode-select -p
```

to see what the path is before compiling, but it did not solve this problem.

Previously I also had this assembly output after upgrading Xcode to the latest version 8.0 when my Mac OS was not upgraded to macOS Sierra yet (it was El Capitan previously), but changing the path solved the problem (as described here: ["warning: section "__const_coal" is deprecated" error after updating Xcode to latest version on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502921/warning-section-const-coal-is-deprecated-error-after-updating-xcode-to-la)). However, it resurfaced again when I upgraded to macOS Sierra, and changing the path did not help this time.

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of the assembly output? I can still compile but it is just annoying to have to waft through all the unnecessary assembly output when debugging.

The output is here:

```
Ivans-MacBook-Pro:CS6771A4-BTree ivanteong$ make
g++ -Wall -Werror -O2 -std=c++14 -fsanitize=address -o test01 test01.cpp
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:1:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:1:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:739:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:739:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:1465:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:1465:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:2742:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:2742:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:6581:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:6581:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:12082:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:12082:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:12485:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:12485:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:12864:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:12864:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:13314:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/3d/hqly97ld37b1kd6wx9gjn2tc0000gn/T//ccslWRTb.s:13314:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Ivans-MacBook-Pro:CS6771A4-BTree ivanteong$
```

Comment: I've been having the exact same issue and haven't found a solution so far. It seems like it's a bug and we need to wait for it to get fixed: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/4812

Comment: It seems that by including the following when compiling at the end, it will prevent the output:                                                                                 2>&1 >/dev/null[:space:]]*\.section' -e '^[[:space:]]*\^[[:space:]]*~*'                                                                      The URL that suggested this (it seems to be a temp fix but will work for now): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865367/warning-section-textcoal-nt-is-deprecate-since-updating-to-mac-osx-sierra