# I keep getting the error "This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421)" on upload

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Like I said in the title, I keep getting the error ["This Action Could Not Be Completed. Try Again. (-22421)"](https://i.imgur.com/1INWI2w.png) when trying to upload my app to iTunes connect. I did it a few weeks ago and it worked fine. Since then I only made a few small text changes, nothing major, and not it won't work.

I looked around and people were saying it could be an issue with Apples servers but its been 4 days now since I've been trying.

I've also noticed when I archive my app I get the error ["section "__const_coal" is deprecated"](https://i.imgur.com/ywPw0PP.png) in Xcode 8.2.1. This doesn't show up when I build or run on my phone, but only when I archive. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502921/warning-section-const-coal-is-deprecated-error-after-updating-xcode-to-la) on stack overflow and tried it but it didn't work and other than that I've found no solutions.

I really need to push this update but I'm completely lost on what to try next.

If anyone can help me fix this I will be forever grateful!

Comment: Image links are both dead.  In the future, please put the text of any relevant errors in your post instead, or use Stack Overflow's own image hosting if the image itself is important.

Comment: did you have a solution eventually? I have the exact same problem you are describing

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a couple of days ago.

You need to manually update the iTMSTransporter.

To do it just open a terminal and run the following code:

```
cd ~  
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

It should show something like:

```
<main>  INFO: Transporter is searching for updated software components.
```

It took about 10 minutes to finish in my case, but I was on a really slow connection.

Tell me if it worked for you too!

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solutions:
Use **Application Loader** to upload your app, as Xcode organizer can't upload file (rejects IPA) sometimes, without genuine reason and it's frequently occurring issue, with Xcode Organizer, that apple could not resolve permanently.

**Solution for error code: 22421**

> - Apple app upload server is not working properly (not in
>     connection or lost connection during file upload). Just wait and try
>     again later (may be after a day).
> - Fluctuation in your network
>     connection, during file upload.
> - You may not have added privacy
>     statements in your info.plist file.

[Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html): Here, is list of keys (with privacy statements) that you should consider to add in your info.plist file, if you have used that service in your application.

**Nowadays, you may also face, this error code: 90186 (with app loader)**

> - Outdated application loader can be reason of this error. Use [latest Xcode tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) and use application loader from Xcode Tool.
> - Incorrect/invalid provisioning profile, associated with your build. Ensure, your have used correct provisioning profile (A provisioning
>     profile with **Distribution/Production** mode is require. A *Development mode* provisioning profile won't allow your to upload app on store.)

You can find latest Application Loader Tool from latest Xcode Tool: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

[image]